# Magento 2 | Flush catalog images in production mode

Tags: magento2, php, product-images, cache, catalog

I updated the photos of the products already existing on my site in Magento2 and they are in production mode.
Unfortunately I don't see the updated photos, not even when I clear all the cache so I guess I will have to clear the cache of the catalog images.

The question is: What happened if I clear the cache of the catalog images from the backend while they are in production mode?
Will the photos be regenerated automatically?
I would like to update all the photos without having to run the command:  `php bin / magento catalog: image: resize`

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried with the content deploy command?

Comment: Yes man, but content deploy command not regenerate or update catalog images but only files of var/view_preprocessed